# Django - Internationalized URL part different per language

Tags: django, internationalization, django-urls, django-localeurl

I need to make an urlpattern different for each language, but following to the same view.

for example:

```
url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/, 'news.views.category', name='category'), in english
url(r'^kategoria/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/, 'news.views.category', name='category'), in polish
```

if you have EN set, "kategoria" won't work. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Django-version>=1.4. check [internationalization for URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-url-patterns).
You can define translations for URLs using `ugettext_lazy()` or you can use `i18n_patterns`

Answer (score 0):

You should not create URL patterns like this `.use` i18n patterns in URL, in `urls.py`:

```
from django.translation import ugettext as _
```

Then make your URL patterns like this:

```
url(_(r'^category/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/))
```

The translators will translate it.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​I don't know if my edit was correct or not, but please try to make your posts clear and awesome. For example that you should always use **4 spaces** to format long line/block of code. And \`code\` (backticks) to format a inline code. For more information, see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You should check and correct these grammar and spelling mistakes before you post your post also, thanks.